# Emscripten C++ Library Link

Tags: javascript, c++, linker, libraries, emscripten

I have a basic C++ GLUT program and I am trying to run Javascript code from inside C++ functions.  I found Emscripten and done lots of testing, but I can't figure out how to actually use it in my projects.  I added the emscripten folder to my compiler's search directories and was able to #include , but I keep getting 'Undefined reference to emscripten_run_script.'  I know this is a problem with not linking the libraries (-1SDL, -1glew32, etc.).  I checked examples and tutorials from the Emscripten website, but I don't need code, I need example projects or just the name and location of the Emscripten library.  How do I link Emscripten so that I can call Emscripten functions from my program, or is it even possible?

EDIT:

Since Emscripten is a Javascript compiler, is there a way I can (instead of linking the library to my project) have Emscripten stand in as the compiler for part of the code, then switch back to g++?

Comment: Are you sure Emscripten is what you need? From a quick look at first Google hits, it seems to be a C++->Javascript compiler, not a Javascript interpreter.

Comment: On their website they have a section called Calling JavaScript from C/C++.  It has examples of cpp files including emscripten.h, which i was able to do, and called functions like emscripten_run_script.

Comment: Well, compiling your C++ program to javascript would technically let you execute javascript in your "c++" functions...sort of :p

Comment: I'm not able to compile my program to javascript because i am using glut and opengl functions.

Comment: Although I did try to use the emscripten command prompt to convert my c++ code to js :D

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example project that works when you add calls to emscripten_run_script. Download [Tim Hutton's OpenGL sample program in C++](https://github.com/timhutton/opengl-canvas-wasm) and add this code as the first line of the main() function:

```
emscripten_run_script("alert('hi')");
```

It works perfectly. I have just tested it and it displays an alert as designed. I used the latest [Emscripten SDK](https://emscripten.org/docs/getting_started/downloads.html) on Windows and used this command to compile main.cpp:

```
emcc main.cpp -s WASM=1 -s USE_SDL=2 -O3 -o index.js
```

I also tried the inline JavaScript method using EM_JS. You can read about all these things [here](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html).

I have tested this both when compiling to WebAssembly (**-s WASM=1**) and to JavaScript (**-s WASM=0**). Both cases work perfectly and have identical behaviour.